# Integral of an extended function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f :(0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that
$$
f(x) = e^{-x} \quad \forall x \in ( 0, \infty )
$$
and
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx < \infty. \tag{1}
$$
Now consider an extension $F$ of $f$ such that
$$
F(x) = e^{-x} \quad \forall x \in (0 - \delta, \infty)
$$
for some $\delta>0$.

Does it necessarily follow that
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx \overset{?}{=} \int_{0}^{\infty} F(x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{ \infty } e^{-x} dx \quad?
$$
Thinking in terms of the Lebesgue measure one would get
$$
\int_{ [0, \infty)} F(x) \, \mu(dx) = \int_{ (0, \infty)} F (x) \, \mu (dx) = \int_{ (0, \infty)} f (x) \, \mu (dx),
$$
and it seems that the question then becomes does it hold
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} F(x) dx \overset{?}{=} \int_{(0, \infty )} F ( x ) \mu ( dx )
$$
and
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx \overset{?}{=} \int_{(0, \infty )} f ( x ) \mu ( dx ).
$$

---

P.S.
Is
$$
\lim_{ y \downarrow 0} \int_{y}^{\infty} f (x) \, dx
$$
the only way of understanding $(1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lebesgue measure of $\{0\}$ is $0$. It makes no difference whether you use the open interval $(0,\infty)$ or the closed interval $[0,\infty)$. So the  integrals are equal.

Comment: I know that the Lebesgue measure of singletons is zero. But are the Lebesgue and Riemann integrals always equal?

Comment: The Riemann integral of any Riemann integrable function on $[a,b]$ coincides with the Lebesgue integral. @Holden

Comment: And if the upper limit is $\infty$ as in the question?

Comment: @Holden That casues no problem. You can just integrate unto $n$ and let $n \to \infty$. The improper Riemann integral becomes equal to the Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to mention that if you integrate unto $n$ and let $n \to \infty$, as mentioned in the comments, then the improper Riemann integral need not be equal to the Lebesgue integral in general. (In this case it is equal though!)

For example, consider $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx = \lim_{a \downarrow 0, b \uparrow \infty} \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$, yet $\int_{0}^{\infty} (\frac{\sin(x)}{x})^{\pm} d\lambda(x) = \infty$ so the Lebesgue integral is not defined in that case.

In general if f is a non-negative function, Riemann integrable such that $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx < \infty$, so $f \colon (0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$, the Lebesgue integral $\int_{(0,\infty)}f d\lambda$ will be equal to $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx$.

Indeed if you set $f_n \equiv \chi_{(0,n]}f$ for all $n$, then $f_n \nearrow f$ as $n \to \infty$ and this sequence is increasing. By the Monotone convergence Theorem of the Lebesgue integral

$$\tag1\int_{(0,\infty)}f d\lambda = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{(0,n]}f d\lambda(x)$$

$$\tag2\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{n}f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx$$

where (1) equals (2) since the Riemann integral exists, (in the sense of proper Riemann integrals) and thus by a standard Theorem is equal to the Lebesgue integral.